# ffmpeg: Set the language of an audio stream without touching other metadata

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, title

I have a MP4 file with an audio stream set to English. I want to change the language of audio stream to French.
I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c: copy -metadata:s:v language=und -metadata:s:a:0 language=fre output.mp4
```

The language of audio stream changes to French without any issues, however, the "Title" of language is lost.

Initially the audio stream was like this:
**Language: English

Title: AC3 5.1 Channels**

After changing the language to French it is like this:
**Language: French

Title: empty**

How should I modify the command so it does not touch the other attributes such as "Title"?

Thanks

Comment: Add `-map_metadata 0` before the manual metadata options.

Comment: I did that, but it did not work. Still the title will be removed.